# How can I shorten name in knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

I think, I need custom binding,

If text is longer than n characters, place "..." and show tooltip onmouseover.

```
<div data-bind="shortenText:name, maxLength:10" ></div>
```

Comment: You're right, there is no build-in binding for that.

Comment: You can use ko.computed to bind truncated text and usual binding for tooltip

Comment: Good idea but I have to create computed property for each property that needs this feature.

Comment: You can create one computed property that will accept a property name as argument and than return truncated text by this property name

Comment: Yes I got it. I want to truncate all text properties so my javascript class will be "property garbage".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can write custom binding without tooltip:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.truncatedText = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        length = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().length) || ko.bindingHandlers.truncatedText.defaultLength,
        truncatedValue = value.length > length ? value.substring(0, Math.min(value.length, length)) + " ..." : value;

        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () { return truncatedValue; });
    },
    defaultLength: 15
};
```

Comment: Would this work with a dynamic default length?

Answer (score 8):

Use a css3 class with the text-overflow: ellipsis property

```
.truncate {
    width: 140px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: How is this using knockout.js?